# The same code, different results VSCode and Github Pages

Tags: github-pages

So, I imported a template from HTML5 and when I run it with a live server on VSC the result is very different from what I get when I open my GitHub Page.

Can anyone help me? What am I missing?

[What I get from VSC LiveServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXgrW.png)

[What I get from GitHub Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQTL3.png)

My Github repository: https://github.com/joasbezerra/github.io

[What I get from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O39lB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Github pages. After doing some research here is how I fixed my page.

Things to watch:

1- excessive space in your CSS

Avoid this:

```
.text{
  text-align: left;

  margin-top:10px;

}



.p{
  text-align: left;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

This will work better:

```
.text{
  text-align: left;
  margin-top:10px;
}
.p{
  text-align: left;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

Also, uppercase will mess up your page. Try to change everything you can to lowercase(folder names, class names, etc..)

Comment: jquery.poptrox.min.js:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.js:98 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrolly is not a function
    at main.js:98:17
    at main.js:123:3

This is what I get from console when I open my Github Page.